# Calling a function that's in another object

Tags: javascript, html, oop, web

When trying to call a function that is in another object than the one I'm calling from, I get the following error: 'ObjectOneInstance is not defined.'

I understand that one option is to insert the statement

`ObjectOneInstance.ObjectTwoInstance = ObjectTwoInstance;`

(or vice versa) change the function to call something like

`this.ObjectTwoInstance.two_A();`.

This way seems to work decently, but I am wondering if there is a different way to do it that is considered better or more proper in the JavaScript field, as the latter example seems abnormal and confusing.

I have been trying to make my Javascript more object-oriented recently, which perhaps has evoked some misunderstanding of what object-oriented JavaScript is structured like when applications become more complex.

```
window.onload = function() {

    var ObjectOneInstance = Object.create(ObjectOne);
    var ObjectTwoInstance = Object.create(ObjectTwo);
    ObjectOneInstance.one_A();

}

var ObjectOne = {

    one_A : function(){
        ObjectTwoInstance.two_A();
    }
}

var ObjectTwo = {

    two_A : function(){
        //do something

    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. `ObjectTwoInstance` doesn't exist in the scope of `one_A()`, so why would you be able to use it there?

Comment: @333 I understand I wouldn't be able to use it there, but I am searching for a solution that will allow me to use it there excluding the one I mentioned.

Comment: I don't mean to sound harsh, but OOP does not mean that objects can magically exist where they are not declared. If you want to be able to access `ObjectTwoInstance` within `one_A`, then you must either declare `ObjectTwoInstance` in an outer scope or pass it as a parameter to `one_A`.

Comment: Because of variable hoisting in javascript , ObjectOne and ObjectTwo will be undefined in window.onload function...You need to move declaration of ObjectOne and ObjectTwo before window.onload function...Also, since ObjectTwoInstance scope is window.onload function, ObjectTwoInstance won't be available in ObjectOne's one_A function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is good lesson in scoping and understanding *when* variables need to be defined.

Let's start with the easiest bit:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var ObjectOneInstance = Object.create(ObjectOne);
    var ObjectTwoInstance = Object.create(ObjectTwo);
    ObjectOneInstance.one_A();
}
```

In javascript variables created with `var` are scoped to the enclosing function. This means that `ObjectOneInstance` and `ObjectTwoInstance` are only available within the function you just created. Outside of this function they don't exist.

To get around this, you can move the declarations outside the function where they will be visible to everyone, but there's a catch:

```
/* BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK…FOR A DIFFERENT REASON */
var ObjectOneInstance = Object.create(ObjectOne);
var ObjectTwoInstance = Object.create(ObjectTwo);

window.onload = function() {
    ObjectOneInstance.one_A();
}
```

Now `ObjectOneInstance` and `ObjectTwoInstance` are in scope where everything can see them, but they depend on `ObjectOne` and `ObjectTwo`, which haven't been defined yet…so you get a different error:

> TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null.

The key is to get everything in the right scope AND the right order. This can be a little subtle with javascript because the objects need to be defined when they are evaluated or functions are called, which is not necessarily the same time the script loads. A lot of things in javascript like `unload` handlers happen asynchronously, which means the whole script runs and *then* the `onload` handler fires. This shouldn't throw errors:

```
window.onload = function() {
  /* ObjectOneInstance is not defined when the script loads, 
     but it will be when onload is called */
  ObjectOneInstance.one_A();
}

var ObjectOne = {
  one_A : function(){
      /* It doesn't matter that ObjectTwoInstance is not defined yet;
         it will be by the time this function is called */
      ObjectTwoInstance.two_A();
  }
}
var ObjectTwo = {
  two_A : function(){
      //do something
  }
}
/* Object create is not in an async handler it runs right away, 
   so ObjectOne and ObjectTwo need to be defined before calling this */
var ObjectOneInstance = Object.create(ObjectOne);
var ObjectTwoInstance = Object.create(ObjectTwo)
```

Comment: Thanks @Mark_M for the great answer! This concept makes a lot more sense to me now.